# Converting avi to divx, are there any c# libraries for divx?

Tags: .net, divx

I have a problem (or maybe a discussion). I've been surfing the Internet in search of program that can convert (DV) avi files in batches to Divx. I'm not an avid person on the subject of codecs and videoformats but I have an straightforward wish to be able to convert my video files to divx.

I was sitting with about 100 GB (I have a lot more, still on tape...) of raw DV material that I had transferred to my computer, but I found it was a hard time to find a program that could do this based on a schedule or more job-like. I was hoping to find a program that could take all files based on filename at a given time start converting and joining files. Since this is quite a time consuming process I was hoping to get this done at nightime...

But after I've searching and trying out a bunch of programs, more or less useful, I started thinking in the terms of making a simple(?) commandline application doing exactly what i wanted to do. So the next step was to find some sort of libraries that could help me do this, but I had a hard time to find any (hopefully something in c#). It this due to licensing or any other misconduct between Microsoft products and the more Open source people of video codecs...? Or maybe there really exist something I could use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of any managed libraries, but you might be able to:

1. Wrap libavcodec (from the FFMPeg project) and/or similar libraries in managed wrappers to achieve your aim;
2. Use FFMPEG (or x264 or MEncoder), launching them from your own managed application and taking note of error codes and whatnot.

Please remember not to violate any licenses, as you mentioned. All the best